# Swift: UITableView does not update with reloadData

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView subview that should display Game Center names, but does not update when reloadData() is called.

The code initiating the tableView and the reloadData function are as follows:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import GameKit

class LobbyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var lobbyView: UITableView!
var lobbyTimer = NSTimer()
var bStartOfTimer: Bool = false
var timerTextView: UITextView = UITextView()


//TABLE VIEW
func initTableView() {
    lobbyView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 150, self.view.frame.width - 40, 2*self.view.frame.height/3), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    lobbyView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    lobbyView.registerClass(LobbyViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    //lobbyView.frame = CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.height/3, self.view.frame.width - 40, self.view.frame.height/3)

    lobbyView.delegate = self
    lobbyView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var background = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    background.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: cs_navy)
    self.view.addSubview(background)

    addText()
    lobbyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.02, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    initTableView()

    self.view.addSubview(lobbyView)
}

    func update(){
    if (lobbyView != nil) {
        self.lobbyView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I have all the other necessary functions, and reloadData() was working until I changed the tableView to a subview. Could the dataSource be incorrect?

Comment: where u called the function name **update**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the previous case but I'm assuming that your controller was a `UITableViewController`. In that case, the main view of the controller was a `UITableView`. However when you switch to a `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` programmatically, you need to make sure your `UITableView` is in the front in your view hierarchy. Try using

```
self.view.insertSubview(lobbyView, 0)
```

instead of

```
self.view.addSubview(lobbyView)
```